# command-line editing in MS sqlcmd on linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, sqlcmd

Is there any way to get any kind of command-line editing in Microsoft's sqlcmd on linux? It looks like the only thing it supports is a destructive backspace. I'm using this version:

```
$ sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 11.0.2270.0 Linux
Copyright (c) 2012 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
```

Or if this won't do it, is there another command line tool I can use to access SQL Server 2014 from a linux box?

Comment: If you use the [-Q option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568447(v=sql.110).aspx) to run queries from the command line, you can use bash editing

Comment: The only thing I'm aware of is [SQLShell](http://software.clapper.org/sqlshell/), but I'm not sure if it has the features you're looking for.  It's been years since I've used it, and even longer since I've seen someone prefer command line tools to a GUI like  TOAD or SQuirreL SQL or DBeaver or Aqua Data Studio for SQL development.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [rlwrap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) and start it as `rlwrap sqlcmd`.  That should give you readline editing capabilities, just like in bash.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) has what you want.  It includes a variety of command-line utilities that use the GNU readline library.

You might also try [sqsh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqsh/), which is loaded with features.  It uses FreeTDS's CT-library, which doesn't support all the latest Microsoft datatypes, but is very useful nonetheless.